# Embed image inside Gmail message, not as an attachment

Tags: gmail, embed

How I can embed an image in a Gmail message body without appending or making it an attachment?

Comment: also see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/cant-see-insert-image-button-in-gmail-when-composing-a-mail

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to enable that option in Labs.

```
Gear icon > Settings > Labs > Insert Image (enable)
```

Comment: You can also click on the small green icon next to settings to take you straight to the Labs settings. (If you already have some labs features on)

Comment: @AlasdairCM: That little icon was lost some redesigns ago.