# Can't see "Insert image" button in Gmail when composing a mail

Tags: gmail

When I'm composing a mail in Gmail I want to insert an image directly in the mail's body, but there is no "Insert image" button at the top. How can I configure it to be visible?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's obsolete. The option to add images was graduated from labs several years ago. See the article from Gmail Help [Send attachments with your Gmail message](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?hl=en). Related official announcement (October, 2012) [Introducing the new compose in Gmail](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2012/10/introducing-new-compose-in-gmail.html)

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to insert an image in the body of the mail:

- drag-and-drop it from its folder to the desired position in the message (depending on your browser, it might or might not work);
- enable the **Insert image** feature from the mail settings and click on the *Insert image* button (this option requires that the email is composed using *Rich formatting*).
  [image]← **new look**
  [image]← **old look**

To enable "Insert image":

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Click on the **Labs** tab
3. Search for **Inserting images** feature
   [image]
4. Click on the **Enable** option
5. Click **Save Changes** at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, by default there is no button:

[image]

If you want to insert an image from your computer to the body of your email, use **drag-and-drop** from your desktop (or file manager) to your web browser.

This drag-and-drop uses HTML5 so it will not work on old browsers.

Alternatively, you can enable the button as described by Alex, but it is a Labs feature, so it *"may change, break or disappear at any time"*.
I guess Google just wants us to become familiar with HTML5 drag-and-drop.

Comment: Where did you get there's no button indeed?

Comment: @crucifiedsoul: See screenshot. It depends on the user's settings, and it might also depend on whether you have old look/new look.